# Joomla - How can i add custom feedback and contact us pages?

Tags: joomla, contacts, joomla2.5

I am a beginner to joomla, in a joomla website i want to create two custom forms ie, contact us and feedback forms. How can i add this forms? I want to give the links for this in footer menu.

I have a custom set of fields for this form..Any help will be appreciated..

Answer (score 2):

you can use ChronoForms, one of the most popular joomla extension to create custom forms

Download the appropriate package as per your joomla version from here 
http://www.chronoengine.com/downloads.html

<s>You can also check out the tutorials on how to use this extension here 
http://www.chronoengine.com/tutorials/154-v4-tutorials.html</s> --- *edit: outdated link, 404*